# Passing array with in GAE Endpoints

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am just trying out the first example of GAE Endpoints, I modified the sample API Method to resemble this.

```
@ApiMethod(name = "sayHi")
public MyBean sayHi(@Named("name") String[] names) {
```

My expectation is to receive a array of strings.
Now when I use the Google API Explorer to test this, [https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/]
it generates API like this

```
POST https://myprojectid.appspot.com/_ah/api/myApi/v1/sayHi/arg1/arg2/arg3?fields=data
```

[image: API explorer screenshot]

It eventually returns `404` error. Since the endpoint is not recognized.

What am I doing wrong here? In fact explorer shows `name` as `String` not `String[]`. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having an array as a parameter of the endpoint method, you should put an object (java bean) which contains an array as a property.

Then you get the object in your method and you just read the property and treat it as an array.

**Edit after some more research, following your comment**

Indeed when you try to pass an array as a Path parameter it doesn't work. The different elements of your array are added to the URL (as you show in your question) and it generates a 404 Not Found error. The trick is that you should pass this array as a Query parameter and not a Path Parameter. See this doc: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/parameter-and-return-types#path_parameters

And indeed, if you do something like that it works very well:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "sayHi",
        path = "sayHiWithName")
public MyBean sayHi(@Named("name") String[] names) {
    MyBean response = new MyBean();
    response.setData("Hi, " + names[0] + names[1]);

    return response;
}
```

Note that the parameter is NOT added to the path (i.e. we don't have a path like sayHiWithName/{name}).

Comment: Sounds like a  solution. But from an academic point of view, what is the right way to pass raw arrays? Because the documentation says, it is possible to pass arrays/collections.

Comment: @Codevalley: I have done some more "research" and tries, and I've added some elements of response to my initial answer.

Answer (score 1):

First things first: does this work when there is a single String parameter?  There's some servlet mapping magic that needs to happen to expose endpoints, and if that is not present in the project, things won't work.  See [this link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/required_files#webxml) to make sure your web.xml is as it should be.

Looking at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/parameter-and-return-types#supported_parameter_types), it seems that if your method parameter is a basic type (not a real Java object), and if it is not specifically included in a @Path annotation, there's some uncertainty in what will happen in your Api:

> Path parameters are the method parameters included in the path property of the @ApiMethod annotation. **If path is unspecified, any parameters not annotated with @Nullable or @DefaultValue will be automatically added to the path** (they will be path parameters).

So it seems that by not including "name" in a `@Path` annotation, the docs don't state what the format of the path will be.  The generated descriptor that the Explorer is looking at seems to think the right answer is `/names[0]/names[1]/names[2]`, kind of like C-style varargs.  It might be this disconnect that causes your 404 to happen.  Can you try by including "name" in a `@Path` annotation?

Comment: Will check this out. Thanks!